# Caching calendar data from Google Calendar

Tags: python, django, caching, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I need to pull events from a Google Calendar in order to present them on a site built with Django. I'm not sure what's the best way of doing it, but I believe the data should be cached (my site/app doesn't use any caching today).

As I don't need an event archive, I'm want to avoid using the db.

This is the approach I'm considering:

1. (0) Check age of cached calendar file, if too old:
2. Download iCalendar (.ics) file from Google (not sure if I should use ics. Maybe RSS/XML is better?)
3. Parse file with iCalendar ([Python iCalendar lib](http://codespeak.net/icalendar/))
4. Generate / render new html output from calendar which can be included as static file and presented on the Django site

Suggestions for improving the procedure, or parts of it, is appreciated.

UPDATE: I've considered using JavaScript, but then if the API is down the data will be unavailable. But if this is considered an acceptable solution, I'll have to look more into it.

Comment: Just a question, how come you arent using the google client library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd agree with @marr75, in that you can probably achieve what you want to do using JavaScript (see Google's [JavaScript page for the GCal API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_js.html)).

One solution would be to write your own [custom management command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) that populates Django's [low level cache](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api), and then use these variables inside your template. You could then set up this management command to run periodically as a cronjob to keep the data fresh. You don't have to cache individual variables - you could always cache a whole block of HTML constructed using iCalendar (which I'm assuming is [this](http://codespeak.net/icalendar/)).

If you gave a little more detail of what it is then I can give an answer that's slightly more helpful than that. As an aside, you might also want to have a look at Django's [per-view cache decorator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache).

**EDIT:** An example might look like this:

```
from django.core.cache import cache

# Generate HTML block to cache
html = '<div>Calendar</div>'

# Cache the HTML as 'google_calendar'
cache.set('google_calendar', html, 3600)
```

And then in your view, you can just pass that cached HTML back to it like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.cache import cache

def home(request):
    data = {
        'gcal': cache.get('google_calendar')
    }
    return render_to_response('home.html', data)
```

Comment: Caching a block of html is what I was thinking of. Can this be cached in memory or will I have to use memcached or similar?

Comment: You can use any of the caches that Django supports, which are [listed here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHES). Make sure you read the documentation for the version of Django that you're using though, as this has changed recently.

Comment: I've also edited my answer so that it includes an example for you.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a suitable approach.

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to avoid caching by making ajax calls and the javascript version of the gdata client library.

Are there features of "iCalendar" (is this a python module for manipulating this kind of data?) you can't replicate using javascript?

This approach would save you storage and processing and most likely give you the most responsive site.

Comment: ....but then if the google calendar is unavailable for any reason, the site won't work.

Comment: It should be possible to do the same kind of manipulation with JS, but I feel it'd be safer to cache data locally if the API is inaccessible.

Comment: Well, while I do realize that the gdata API has downtime, do you anticipate (or require) better availability than google's APIs? If so, you could fallback to a recent copy.